# Histogram and any curve on the same plot in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Can anyone help me or give me some tips how to create histogram and curve on same plot? When I try to do it, gnuplot is plotting a histogram or a curve, but not both of them.

This is code I used:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -persist   
f(x)=99*0.03*(1/(0.062*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-((x-1.28)**2)/(2*(0.062**2)))    
set xrange [1:1.43]   
set yrange [0:25] noreverse nowriteback    
plot f(x)  
set boxwidth 2 absolute   
set style fill solid 1.00 border lt -1   
set style histogram clustered gap 1 title  offset character 0, 0, 0    
set datafile missing '-'   
set style data histograms  
set xtics border in scale 0,0 nomirror offset character 0, 0, 0   
set xtics  norangelimit   
set xtics   ()   
i = 23     
replot 'histogram1.txt' using 2:xtic(1)   
set output 'histogram1.png'        `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not having the data set you are plotting, I must guess how the final result should look like...

When plotting histograms, gnuplot implicitely places the boxes at integer x-values, starting at `0`, and with custom xtics, when having `using 2:xtic(1)`. You set the xrange to `[1:1.43]` to plot your function properly. Probably you want to plot `with boxes` to get it right.

Try:

```
f(x)=99*0.03*(1/(0.062*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-((x-1.28)**2)/(2*(0.062**2)))    
set xrange [1:1.43]   
set yrange [0:25]   

set boxwidth 0.8 relative   
set style fill solid 1.00 border lt -1   
set datafile missing '-'   

plot f(x), 'histogram1.txt' using 1:2 with boxes
```